# UITableView appearing with an animation (expanding from a corner)

Tags: objective-c, animation

I am not able to expand a UITable from a corner.

This is what I do:

```
 tableAccounts = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 71, 0,0)];
        [self.view addSubview:tableAccounts];


        [UIView beginAnimations:@"tableAppearing" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0f];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

        tableAccounts.frame = CGRectMake(0, 71, 320, 332);
        tableAccounts.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

I can see the table appearing from the top left corner, but not expanding! I mean that the table never changes its size, its always the same size and it is appearing.
I want the same effect but starting with a tiny table, and being bigger.

It is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that by applying a scale transform to the tableview and moving it from the corner. The following should grow from the bottom right corner.

```
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
int width = CGRectGetWidth(frame);
int height = CGRectGetHeight(frame);

// Make the frame the size you want in the end and place it centered on the corner.
CGRect startTvFrame = CGRectMake(width / 2, height / 2, width, height);
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:startTvFrame];

// Scale the view so that it starts out small
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.001, .001);
tableView.transform = t;

[self.view addSubview:tableView];

// Animations
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f 
                      delay:0.0f 
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear 
                 animations:^{
                     // Reset the scale
                     tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);

                     // Position the tableview
                     CGRect tvFrame = tableView.frame;
                     tvFrame.origin.x = 0;
                     tvFrame.origin.y = 0;
                     tableView.frame = tvFrame;
                 }
                 completion:nil];

[tableView release];
```